# update table row and save in database in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am making a table from a database and want to add an Edit/delete button to each row update or delete a specific row from the database. I have successfully added working "delete" button but I have no idea how could I update data in table `<td>` in view and send it to controller.

Here is my code:

**view file**

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>age</td>
    <td>gender</td>
    <td>class</td>
    <td>roll no.</td>
  </tr>
  <?php foreach($record as $r): ?>
  <tr>
   <td><?php echo $r->name; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $r->age; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $r->gender; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $r->class; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $r->roll no; ?></td>
   <td><a href="" >Edit</a>
     <a href="<?php echo base_url()."student/deleteRow" ?id="$r->name">"                                       
           onclick="return confirm
           ('Are you sure  to Delete?')"><i class="icon-trash"></a></td>

  </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Controller Function

```
public function deleteRow(){

    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
      $id=$this->input->get('id');

      $this->student_model->rowDelete($id);

      redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);  
    }
}
```

I don't know how can I now insert an input field to update table row without effecting previous view. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: See this [menual](https://www.formget.com/insert-data-into-database-using-codeigniter/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Edit the Studen data you need to pass an id or uniue column name to the data base to get that student data.

First Set the student id in `<a href="">` tag.

```
<td><a href="<?= base_url('student/edit_student') ?>/$r->id" >Edit</a>
```

Then When you click on the edit it will take you to the controller. You can get the third url parameter direct in as show in the controler code:
You can also use get as shon

Your Controller should be:

```
public function edit_student($id){

 $student_data = $this->student_model->get_student_data($id);

 $this->load->view('your_view',['student_data'=>$student_data)]);

}
```

Here is you model which get the id form controllr and find the student data and passit to back to the controller:
Your Model should be:

```
public function get_student_data($id){

 $this->db->select('*');
 $this->db->from('your_table_name');
 $this->db->where('id',$id);
 $query = $this->db->get();

 $student_data = $query->$row_array();

 if(isset($student_data) && !empty($student_data)){

    return student_data;

 } else {

    return FALSE;

 }

}
```

Form controller you pass the data to the view.
On View Side:

```
<?php 
// Just to ensure the data. Comment it after testing
echo "<pre>";
print_r($student_data);
echo "</pre>";

?>


<form action="<?= base_url('student/update_student') ?>/<?= $student_data['id'] ?>">

<input name="your_column_name" value="<?= $student_data['your_column_name'] ?>">
// Try to do the same for all you column.

<input type="submit" value="updata">

</form>
```

Here is the controller for update the data

```
public function update_student($id){

 $student_data = $this->input->post();  
 $status = $this->student_model->update_student($id,$student_data);

 if($status == TRUE){       
    $this->load->view('your_view');
    // Your Success view        
 } else {
    // Your view if fail to update
    $this->load->view('your_view');     
 }
}
```

Here is the model for update the data

```
public function get_student_data($id,$student_data){

 $this->db->where('id',$id);
 $this->db->update('your_table_name',$student_data);

    if($this->db->affected_rows() == 1){    
        return TRUE;    
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to what you have done for delete. Something like this:

```
<td>
    <a href="" >Edit/Delete</a>
    <a href="<?php echo base_url('student/updateRow?id='.$r->name); ?><i class="icon-edit"></a><!-- This should be another method in Student controller -->
    <a href="<?php echo base_url('student/deleteRow?id='.$r->name); ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure  to Delete?')"><i class="icon-trash"></a><!-- I changed order of edit and delete -->
</td>
```

I need to warn you for CSRF. If you don't implement better security here, anyone pointing to that link would be able to edit or delete data. 
Check [Security class](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html) in documentation and how to set hidden value so that way you would ensure that only one who has already requested that page was able to edit/delete rows.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<td><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>controller_name/function_name/<?php echo $edit_id;?>" >Edit</a></td>


another way 




<td><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>controller_name/function_name?id=<?php echo $edit_id;?>" >Edit</a></td>
```

You can use any one according to your requirement.